# Store data using shared preferences along with date

Tags: android, date, sharedpreferences

I have an app where i need store some data(lets say some integer value). the stored data will increase when ever user make some actions. it work perfectly fine.

But i want to know what is the Stored value everyday so i can make some reports(lets say a monthly report where it shows the stored data each day). Is there anyway i can do this?
I want to know the date or day with each stored value. is it posible? or have any better solution?

Here is shared preference code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    progress=progress+pref.getInt("data", 0);
}

//Some code

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("data",Progress);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Any helpful thoughts are appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Use a SQLite database, where you `insert()` new rows for each day, with the date as one of the columns. Or, use regular files (e.g., JSON, XML), where the date is part of the data that you save.

Comment: its only a integer value that i am storing. is there anyway including date when using shared preferance?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use 1.Sqlite Database as local database to store data and get data . even update or delete . its easy too .
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

2. Or You can store data on web with network call using volley or other network library .

https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: When using local database I can get date as well?

Comment: can you write the sample codes using SQL database. i am pretty new to SQL and been looking for a solution whole day. Thanks

Comment: i have gone through all of them there is any simple codes as im new to SQL. answer with some code samples are much appreciated.

Comment: I somehow managed to create a simple database and now how to add date?

Comment: Here You have find all the way . its easy

Comment: http://tips.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-insert-datetime-value-in-sqlite-database/